# How to get microphone voice level from ByteArray(pcmBuffer)?

Tags: android, audio, voice-recognition, microphone, voice-recording

I have to display microphone voice level, we are displaying seekbar which will increase when when someone is speaking and decrease when there is silence, i don't know what this is called technically, but by doing some research i have found that its called decibel(dB).

There are many answers i have checked [Get the Microphone sound level ( Decibel level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197798/get-the-microphone-sound-level-decibel-level-in-android#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20MediaRecorder.,getMaxAmplitude()%20.&text=Get%20the%20noise%20level%20using,mRecorder%20%3D%20new%20MediaRecorder()%3B%20mRecorder.) but i'm not using `MediaRecorder` so i can't get amplitude as stated in answer, i only have `ByteArray` of current microphone input.

**Now my main question is how i can get microphone voice level(or maybe decibel) from only having `ByteArray`?**

I have also checked many other questions like:
[android-detect-sound-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181449/android-detect-sound-level).
[android-find-decibels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793692/android-how-to-find-decibels).

But most of them suggest to use formula which depends on amplitude or anything else related to amplitude like [aplitudeRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571894/calculate-decibel-from-amplitude-android-media-recorder), so please let me know can i get voice level with only having `ByteArray` of **pcm buffer**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the level/amplitude/db of audio signal in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574326/how-to-calculate-the-level-amplitude-db-of-audio-signal-in-java)

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks for link, but it does not help, because i do not know `TargetDataLine` is there and how/what i can use in my case to at place of it.